Adding exceptional namespace to AdmissionConfiguration in CIS Mode in RKE2 Kubernetes
Using the CIS Mode in RKE2 implies that the following Pod Security Standard is installed during the first installation: https://docs.rke2.io/security/pod_security_standards

Is it possible to "patch" the PodSecurity.configuration.exemptions.namespaces? In particular I would like to add a specific namespace.
